# Packet Tracer: problems with GUI usability and look

Tags: unity, gui, cisco

I have to use packet tracer a lot, and it is very difficult to use now. It hides windows behind the principal window (for example, a window from a router or a pc) and it looks horrible.
What can I do?
Thanks and regards,

PD: System is 64bit ubuntu 11.10 with unity.

Answer (score 1):

The packet tracer window must not be maximized. Then right click on the title bar and select always on top.

Answer (score 0):

Packet tracer uses fonts from internal qt engine.  See this link:
http://pvradu.blogspot.com/2010/04/packet-tracer-52-font-problem.html.  Worked for me.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.